# Multiple css pseudo-class

Tags: css, syntax, nested, pseudo-class

I was wondering, what is the correct syntax to do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){
    .header-toolbar-contact:nth-child(1){
        display: none !important;
    }
    .header-toolbar-contact:nth-child(2){
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

I tried this:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){
    .header-toolbar-contact:not(.header-toolbar-contact:nth-child(3)){
        display: none !important;
    }
}`

But doesn't seems to work.
My question is: how to use multiple pseudo-classes in one declaration. As if it was "nested".

Answer (score 2):

Comma separate the classnames:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){
    .header-toolbar-contact:nth-child(1),
    .header-toolbar-contact:nth-child(2) {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Css allows multiple selectors to use the same rules with comma separated selectors. You can use as many as you wish.

Comment: Also, a note on !important. It's really a last resort thing to use, if it has to be there, something has gone wrong in another place.

Comment: That's because i'm working on a Wordpress child-theme so i have to override some of it's classes. I already knew the comma technic, don't know why i didn't do it though :) My question was really about how to "nest" multiple pseudo-class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sometimes !important is a necessary evil.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing full class name to `:not()` simply pass `:nth-child(3)`

```css
.header-toolbar-contact:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-toolbar-contact">First</div>
<div class="header-toolbar-contact">Second</div>
<div class="header-toolbar-contact">Third</div>
```

Comment: you missed the logic, I believe the author wants child 1 and 2 to have display: none, and child 3 should be display: block or something

Comment: Yes only child 3 should be displayed

Comment: But the question is not how to do that, it's really about how to use multiple pseudo-class in one declaration.